# Checking an array in a file if it's palindrome or not

Tags: java

I'm a little lost and need a bit of help. I want this program to test if strings in a file are palindrome are not. Problem I'm mainly having an issue at is the second for loop. If someone could tell me what I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main (String args []) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File ("Palindromes.txt");
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner (file);
    String [] fileArray = new String [20];
    String [] arrayClean = new String [20];
    char c1, c2;
    boolean palindromeTest = false;
    int numLines = 0;

    while (fileInput.hasNext())
    {
        fileArray[numLines] = fileInput.nextLine();
        numLines++;
    }
    fileInput.close();
    for (int j = 0; j < fileArray.length; j++)
    {
        arrayClean[j] = fileArray[j];
        if (palindromeTest == true)
        {
            System.out.println (fileArray[j] + " is a palindrome.");
        }
        if (palindromeTest == false)
        {
            System.out.println (fileArray [j] + " is not a palindrome.");
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < arrayClean.length / 2; k++)
        {
            c1 = fileArray.charAt(arrayClean.length - k - 1);
            c2 = fileArray.charAt(k);
            if (c2 == c1)
            {
                palindromeTest = true;
            }
            else
            {
                palindromeTest = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_Problem I'm mainly having an issue at is the second for loop_" What problem? Error? Exception? Wrong result? You need to explain what it is doing so we can compare that to what it is supposed to do.

Comment: you can just add the word to a `lists` and call `Collections.reverse(`list`);` and check that string against its not reverse

Answer (score 1):

- You first say whether or not a line is a palindrome, then test it - this way, each line will be printed based on the *previous line's* test.
- The test itself should say `false` when *any* character pair is different; once you've determined it's different, it shouldn't be able to flip to `true` any more. So you'd do this (pseudocode):

  ```
  set palindrome to true-so-far
  loop for half the characters
    if character pair does not match,
      it's not a palindrome after all,
      and we can stop testing
  now we know whether it's still a palindrome, or not a palindrome after all,
  so print the result
  ```
- `arrayClean` is unnecessary, you can do everything with `fileArray`
- `fileArray` is unnecessary, you can do everything in one loop, by reading a line then testing it

The first two are errors; the second two are improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the first half of your string and make sure it matches the second half in reverse order:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length()/2; i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length()-i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and replace your second loop to just check

```
if(isPalindrome(fileArray[j])) {
  System.out.println (fileArray[j] + " is a palindrome.");
}else{
  System.out.println (fileArray[j] + " is not a palindrome.");
}
```